# Dynamic Casting Error

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex, casting

```
        public class DynamicSOQL 
    {

            public static List<Sobject> Soql (String ObjectName, List<String> apiNames,Set<Object> IdsToQuery )
        {
            String query;
            String SobjectApiName = objectName;
            String allstring = string.join(apiNames,',');

            query = 'SELECT ' + allstring + ' FROM ' + SobjectApiName + ' WHERE ID = :IdsToQuery';
            Sobject[] sObjectList = Database.query(query);
            return sObjectList;
            }
    }
```

I am calling this class in the following way:

```
    List<Account> accountsToMerge = (List<Account>)DynamicSOQL.SOQL('Account', apiNames, listOfIds);
```

This is returning the following error message

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void SOQL(String, List<String>, List<String>) from the type DynamicSOQL (24:72)
```

I have a hunch I am not casting correctly

Comment: It's right there in the error, isn't it? `void SOQL(String, List<String>, List<String>)` (what you're trying to call) is different from `void SOQL(String, List<String>, Set<Object>)` (the method signature you have). The last parameter should be a `Set` instead of a `List`, no?

Comment: @DerekF Correct!

Comment: I thought that the Object type would be dynamic

Comment: `Object` is one of the top-level types in Apex (not sure where `null` and the special `Any` type fit in the type system), and is thus abstract to the point of practical uselessness...at least to us mere mortal users.

Comment: The fact that `Object` is an abstractish base class doesn't actually matter much because the concrete collection type is different. `List<anything>` != `Set<anything>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the signature of your method `void SOQL(String, List<String>, Set<Object>)`
is different from the signature of your call `void SOQL(String, List<String>, List<String>)`

There is a constructor for `Set` that takes a `List` (and vice-versa), but you cannot assign a `Set` to a `List`, nor a `List` to a `Set`, nor will explicit type casting work.

With all of that in mind, and a little extra, the minimum amount of change you'd need to make here is to alter the signature of your call so that the third parameter is a `Set<Object>`.

```java
List<Account> accountsToMerge = (List<Account>)DynamicSOQL.SOQL(
    'Account', 
    apiNames, 
    // We need to first cast listOfIds as a List<Object>
    // We can then pass it into the constructor for a Set<Object>
    new Set<Object>((List<Object>)listOfIds)
);
```

That said, I don't think using a `Set<Object>` has any advantage here over, say, `Set<Id>`. I'd reconsider your use of `Set<Object>`.